# jmp to self instruction compiled by gcc4.4.6-3

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a C++ project, run rightly compiled by gcc-4.1.2-46 and gcc-4.4.5-6

But it has an abnormal dead loop while compiled by gcc-4.4.6-3 using -O2.

I use gdb to attach it when the process running, and find the thread is running but the stack does not change.

objdump the program, find that it has 3 instruction jmp to self, like this:

```
   432f6c:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi 
   432f6f:       90                      nop 
   432f70:       e8 b3 e4 fd ff          callq  411428 <_Unwind_Resume@plt> 
   432f75:       eb fe                   jmp    432f75 <_ZN9oceanbase12updateserver11QueryEngine3getERKNS0_5TEKeyE+0x4d5> 
   432f77:       48 8d 7c 24 70          lea    0x70(%rsp),%rdi 
   432f7c:       48 89 c3                mov    %rax,%rbx 
   432f7f:       e8 9c 32 00 00          callq  436220 <_ZN9oceanbase12updateserver12BitLockGuardD1Ev>
```

I have not used "goto" in code.

When the code is compiled by gcc-4.4.6-3 using -O0,

the jmp to self instruction disappeared

So I doubt it is a bug of gcc-4.4.6.3.

The code is a simple multi-thread Hashmap using BitLock to protect the buckets:

```
      #define ATOMIC_CAS(val, cmpv, newv) __sync_val_compare_and_swap((val), (cmpv), (newv))
      #define ATOMIC_ADD(val, addv) __sync_add_and_fetch((val), (addv))
      #define ATOMIC_SUB(val, subv) __sync_sub_and_fetch((val), (subv))

      template <typename Key,
                typename Value,
                typename BucketAllocator,
                typename NodeAllocator>
      class LightyHashMap
      {
        struct Node
        {
          Key key;
          Value value;
          union
          {
            Node *next;
            int64_t flag;
          };
        };
        static const int64_t EMPTY_FLAG = 0xffffffffffffffff;
        static const int64_t INIT_UNIT_SIZE = (64L * 1024L / sizeof(Node)) * sizeof(Node);
        typedef Hash<Key> HashFunc;
        typedef Equal<Key> EqualFunc;
        public:
          LightyHashMap(BucketAllocator &bucket_allocator, NodeAllocator &node_allocator);
          ~LightyHashMap();
        private:
          DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(LightyHashMap);
        public:
          int create(const int64_t bucket_num);
          void destroy();
          int clear();
        public:
          inline int insert(const Key &key, const Value &value);
          inline int get(const Key &key, Value &value);
          inline int erase(const Key &key, Value *value = NULL);
          inline int64_t uninit_unit_num() const;
          inline int64_t bucket_using() const;
          inline int64_t size() const;
        private:
          void init_bucket_unit_(const int64_t bucket_pos);
        private:
          BucketAllocator &bucket_allocator_;
          NodeAllocator &node_allocator_;
          int64_t bucket_num_;
          Node *buckets_;
          volatile int64_t uninit_unit_num_;
          uint8_t *init_units_;
          BitLock bit_lock_;
          int64_t bucket_using_;
          int64_t size_;
          HashFunc hash_func_;
          EqualFunc equal_func_;
      };

      template <typename Key, typename Value, typename BucketAllocator, typename NodeAllocator>
      LightyHashMap<Key, Value, BucketAllocator, NodeAllocator>::LightyHashMap(
        BucketAllocator &bucket_allocator,
        NodeAllocator &node_allocator) : bucket_allocator_(bucket_allocator),
                                         node_allocator_(node_allocator),
                                         bucket_num_(0),
                                         buckets_(NULL),
                                         uninit_unit_num_(0),
                                         init_units_(NULL),
                                         bucket_using_(0),
                                         size_(0),
                                         hash_func_(),
                                         equal_func_()
      {
      }

      template <typename Key, typename Value, typename BucketAllocator, typename NodeAllocator>
      LightyHashMap<Key, Value, BucketAllocator, NodeAllocator>::~LightyHashMap()
      {
        destroy();
      }

      template <typename Key, typename Value, typename BucketAllocator, typename NodeAllocator>
      int LightyHashMap<Key, Value, BucketAllocator, NodeAllocator>::create(const int64_t bucket_num)
      {
        int ret = common::OB_SUCCESS;
        int64_t uninit_unit_num = (bucket_num * sizeof(Node) / INIT_UNIT_SIZE) \
                                  + ((0 == (bucket_num * sizeof(Node) % INIT_UNIT_SIZE)) ? 0 : 1);
        if (NULL != buckets_)
        {
          ret = common::OB_INIT_TWICE;
        }
        else if (0 >= bucket_num)
        {
          ret = common::OB_INVALID_ARGUMENT;
        }
        else if (NULL == (buckets_ = (Node*)bucket_allocator_.alloc(bucket_num * sizeof(Node))))
        {
          ret = common::OB_MEM_OVERFLOW;
        }
        else if (NULL == (init_units_ = (uint8_t*)bucket_allocator_.alloc(uninit_unit_num * sizeof(uint8_t))))
        {
          ret = common::OB_MEM_OVERFLOW;
        }
        else if (OB_SUCCESS != (ret = bit_lock_.init(bucket_num)))
        {
          // init bit lock fail
        }
        else
        {
          bucket_num_ = bucket_num;
          uninit_unit_num_ = uninit_unit_num;
          memset(init_units_, 0, uninit_unit_num_ * sizeof(uint8_t));
          bucket_using_ = 0;
          size_ = 0;
        }
        if (common::OB_SUCCESS != ret)
        {
          destroy();
        }
        return ret;
      }

      template <typename Key, typename Value, typename BucketAllocator, typename NodeAllocator>
      void LightyHashMap<Key, Value, BucketAllocator, NodeAllocator>::destroy()
      {
        if (NULL != buckets_)
        {
          if (NULL != init_units_)
          {
            for (int64_t i = 0; i < bucket_num_; i++)
            {
              int64_t unit_pos = i * sizeof(Node) / INIT_UNIT_SIZE;
              uint8_t ov = init_units_[unit_pos];
              if (0 == (ov & 0x80))
              {
                continue;
              }
              Node *iter = buckets_[i].next;
              while (EMPTY_FLAG != buckets_[i].flag
                    && NULL != iter)
              {
                Node *tmp = iter;
                iter = iter->next;
                node_allocator_.free(tmp);
              }
              buckets_[i].flag = EMPTY_FLAG;
            }
          }
          bucket_allocator_.free(buckets_);
          buckets_ = NULL;
        }
        if (NULL != init_units_)
        {
          bucket_allocator_.free(init_units_);
          init_units_ = NULL;
        }
        bit_lock_.destroy();
        bucket_num_ = 0;
        uninit_unit_num_ = 0;
        bucket_using_ = 0;
        size_ = 0;
      }

      template <typename Key, typename Value, typename BucketAllocator, typename NodeAllocator>
      int LightyHashMap<Key, Value, BucketAllocator, NodeAllocator>::clear()
      {
        int ret = common::OB_SUCCESS;
        if (NULL == buckets_
            || NULL == init_units_)
        {
          ret = common::OB_NOT_INIT;
        }
        else
        {
          for (int64_t i = 0; i < bucket_num_; i++)
          {
            int64_t unit_pos = i * sizeof(Node) / INIT_UNIT_SIZE;
            uint8_t ov = init_units_[unit_pos];
            if (0 == (ov & 0x80))
            {
              continue;
            }
            BitLockGuard guard(bit_lock_, i);
            Node *iter = buckets_[i].next;
            while (EMPTY_FLAG != buckets_[i].flag
                  && NULL != iter)
            {
              Node *tmp = iter;
              iter = iter->next;
              node_allocator_.free(tmp);
            }
            buckets_[i].flag = EMPTY_FLAG;
          }
          uninit_unit_num_ = (bucket_num_ * sizeof(Node) / INIT_UNIT_SIZE) \
                              + ((0 == (bucket_num_ * sizeof(Node) % INIT_UNIT_SIZE)) ? 0 : 1);
          memset(init_units_, 0, uninit_unit_num_ * sizeof(Node));
          bucket_using_ = 0;
          size_ = 0;
        }
        return ret;
      }

      template <typename Key, typename Value, typename BucketAllocator, typename NodeAllocator>
      int LightyHashMap<Key, Value, BucketAllocator, NodeAllocator>::insert(const Key &key, const Value &value)
      {
        int ret = common::OB_SUCCESS;
        if (NULL == buckets_
            || NULL == init_units_)
        {
          ret = common::OB_NOT_INIT;
        }
        else
        {
          int64_t hash_value = hash_func_(key);
          int64_t bucket_pos = hash_value % bucket_num_;
          init_bucket_unit_(bucket_pos);
          BitLockGuard guard(bit_lock_, bucket_pos);
          if (EMPTY_FLAG == buckets_[bucket_pos].flag)
          {
            buckets_[bucket_pos].key = key;
            buckets_[bucket_pos].value = value;
            buckets_[bucket_pos].next = NULL;
            common::atomic_inc((uint64_t*)&bucket_using_);
            common::atomic_inc((uint64_t*)&size_);
          }
          else
          {
            Node *iter = &(buckets_[bucket_pos]);
            while (true)
            {
              if (equal_func_(iter->key, key))
              {
                ret = common::OB_ENTRY_EXIST;
                break;
              }
              if (NULL != iter->next)
              {
                iter = iter->next;
              }
              else
              {
                break;
              }
            }
            if (common::OB_SUCCESS == ret)
            {
              Node *node = (Node*)node_allocator_.alloc(sizeof(Node));
              if(NULL == node)
              {
                ret = common::OB_MEM_OVERFLOW;
              }
              else
              {
                node->key = key;
                node->value = value;
                node->next = NULL;
                iter->next = node;
                common::atomic_inc((uint64_t*)&size_);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        return ret;
      }

      template <typename Key, typename Value, typename BucketAllocator, typename NodeAllocator>
      int LightyHashMap<Key, Value, BucketAllocator, NodeAllocator>::get(const Key &key, Value &value)
      {
        int ret = common::OB_SUCCESS;
        if (NULL == buckets_
            || NULL == init_units_)
        {
          ret = common::OB_NOT_INIT;
        }
        else
        {
          int64_t hash_value = hash_func_(key);
          int64_t bucket_pos = hash_value % bucket_num_;
          init_bucket_unit_(bucket_pos);
          BitLockGuard guard(bit_lock_, bucket_pos);
          ret = common::OB_ENTRY_NOT_EXIST;
          if (EMPTY_FLAG != buckets_[bucket_pos].flag)
          {
            Node *iter = &(buckets_[bucket_pos]);
            while (NULL != iter)
            {
              if (equal_func_(iter->key, key))
              {
                value = iter->value;
                ret = common::OB_SUCCESS;
                break;
              }
              iter = iter->next;
            }
          }
        }
        return ret;
      }

      template <typename Key, typename Value, typename BucketAllocator, typename NodeAllocator>
      int LightyHashMap<Key, Value, BucketAllocator, NodeAllocator>::erase(const Key &key, Value *value)
      {
        int ret = common::OB_SUCCESS;
        if (NULL == buckets_
            || NULL == init_units_)
        {
          ret = common::OB_NOT_INIT;
        }
        else
        {
          int64_t hash_value = hash_func_(key);
          int64_t bucket_pos = hash_value % bucket_num_;
          init_bucket_unit_(bucket_pos);
          BitLockGuard guard(bit_lock_, bucket_pos);
          ret = common::OB_ENTRY_NOT_EXIST;
          if (EMPTY_FLAG != buckets_[bucket_pos].flag)
          {
            Node *iter = &(buckets_[bucket_pos]);
            Node *prev = NULL;
            while (NULL != iter)
            {
              if (equal_func_(iter->key, key))
              {
                if (NULL != value)
                {
                  *value = iter->value;
                }
                if (NULL == prev)
                {
                  buckets_[bucket_pos].flag = EMPTY_FLAG;
                }
                else
                {
                  // do not free deleted node
                  prev->next = iter->next;
                }
                ret = common::OB_SUCCESS;
                break;
              }
              prev = iter;
              iter = iter->next;
            }
          }
        }
        return ret;
      }

      template <typename Key, typename Value, typename BucketAllocator, typename NodeAllocator>
      int64_t LightyHashMap<Key, Value, BucketAllocator, NodeAllocator>::uninit_unit_num() const
      {
        return uninit_unit_num_;
      }

      template <typename Key, typename Value, typename BucketAllocator, typename NodeAllocator>
      int64_t LightyHashMap<Key, Value, BucketAllocator, NodeAllocator>::bucket_using() const
      {
        return bucket_using_;
      }

      template <typename Key, typename Value, typename BucketAllocator, typename NodeAllocator>
      int64_t LightyHashMap<Key, Value, BucketAllocator, NodeAllocator>::size() const
      {
        return size_;
      }

      template <typename Key, typename Value, typename BucketAllocator, typename NodeAllocator>
      void LightyHashMap<Key, Value, BucketAllocator, NodeAllocator>::init_bucket_unit_(const int64_t bucket_pos)
      {
        while (0 < uninit_unit_num_)
        {
          int64_t unit_pos = bucket_pos * sizeof(Node) / INIT_UNIT_SIZE;
          uint8_t ov = init_units_[unit_pos];
          if (ov & 0x80)
          {
            break;
          }
          ov = 0;
          uint8_t nv = ov | 0x01;
          if (ov == ATOMIC_CAS(&(init_units_[unit_pos]), ov, nv))
          {
            int64_t ms_size = std::min((bucket_num_ - bucket_pos) * sizeof(Node), (uint64_t)INIT_UNIT_SIZE);
            memset((char*)buckets_ + unit_pos * INIT_UNIT_SIZE, -1, ms_size);
            ATOMIC_SUB(&uninit_unit_num_, 1);
            init_units_[unit_pos] = 0x80;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
static const uint8_t BIT_MASKS[8] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80};

class BitLock
{
  public:
    BitLock() : size_(0),
                bits_(NULL)
    {
    };
    ~BitLock()
    {
      destroy();
    };
  public:
    inline int init(const int64_t size);
    inline void destroy();
    inline int lock(const int64_t index);
    inline int unlock(const int64_t index);
  private:
    int64_t size_;
    uint8_t *bits_;
};

class BitLockGuard
{
  public:
    BitLockGuard(BitLock &lock, const int64_t index) : lock_(lock),
                                                       index_(index)
    {
      lock_.lock(index_);
    };
    ~BitLockGuard()
    {
      lock_.unlock(index_);
    };
  private:
    BitLock &lock_;
    const int64_t index_;
};

int BitLock::init(const int64_t size)
{
  int ret = common::OB_SUCCESS;
  if (0 < size_
      || NULL != bits_)
  {
    ret = common::OB_INIT_TWICE;
  }
  else if (0 >= size)
  {
    ret = common::OB_INVALID_ARGUMENT;
  }
  else
  {
    int64_t byte_size = common::upper_align(size, 8) / 8;
    if (NULL == (bits_ = (uint8_t*)common::ob_malloc(byte_size)))
    {
      ret = common::OB_MEM_OVERFLOW;
    }
    else
    {
      memset(bits_, 0, byte_size);
      size_ = size;
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

void BitLock::destroy()
{
  if (NULL != bits_)
  {
    common::ob_free(bits_);
    bits_ = NULL;
  }
  size_ = 0;
}

int BitLock::lock(const int64_t index)
{
  int ret = common::OB_SUCCESS;
  if (0 >= size_
      || NULL == bits_)
  {
    ret = common::OB_NOT_INIT;
  }
  else if (index >= size_)
  {
    ret = common::OB_INVALID_ARGUMENT;
  }
  else
  {
    int64_t byte_index = index / 8;
    int64_t bit_index = index % 8;
    while (true)
    {
      uint8_t ov = bits_[byte_index];
      if (ov & BIT_MASKS[bit_index])
      {
        continue;
      }
      if (ov == ATOMIC_CAS(&(bits_[byte_index]), ov, ov | BIT_MASKS[bit_index]))
      {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

int BitLock::unlock(const int64_t index)
{
  int ret = common::OB_SUCCESS;
  if (0 >= size_
      || NULL == bits_)
  {
    ret = common::OB_NOT_INIT;
  }
  else if (index >= size_)
  {
    ret = common::OB_INVALID_ARGUMENT;
  }
  else
  {
    int64_t byte_index = index / 8;
    int64_t bit_index = index % 8;
    while (true)
    {
      uint8_t ov = bits_[byte_index];
      if (!(ov & BIT_MASKS[bit_index]))
      {
        // have not locked
        break;
      }
      if (ov == ATOMIC_CAS(&(bits_[byte_index]), ov, ov & ~BIT_MASKS[bit_index]))
      {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: With no code, noone can help you.  Try to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: It's not only `goto` that can cause your application to go into a loop.

Comment: You possibly could be looking at some form of inlining of a function where the compiler decides to simply jump to the code block rather than making an actual call.  It's hard to say without seeing the original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is in your loop in `BitLock::lock`:

```
    while (true)
    {
      uint8_t ov = bits_[byte_index];
      if (ov & BIT_MASKS[bit_index])
      {
        continue;
      }
      if (ov == ATOMIC_CAS(&(bits_[byte_index]), ov, ov | BIT_MASKS[bit_index]))
      {
        break;
      }
    }
```

The `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` in your `ATOMIC_CAS` macro will act as memory barrier, preventing the compiler/processor from speculating loads across it, but it won't do anything about loads before it, so the condition `ov & BIT_MASKS[bit_index]` could be optimized based on the value of `bits_[byte_index]` before the `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` call and thus resulting in an infinite loop.

Try the following, instead:

```
    while (true)
    {
      uint8_t ov = bits_[byte_index];
      if (ov & BIT_MASKS[bit_index])
      {
        __sync_synchronize();  // or define ATOMIC_SYNC if you prefer
        continue;
      }
      if (ov == ATOMIC_CAS(&(bits_[byte_index]), ov, ov | BIT_MASKS[bit_index]))
      {
        break;
      }
    }
```

The `__sync_synchronize` memory barrier will prevent the loop from degenerating into a trivial one.

Comment: Yes, it does not generate a infinite loop when I add the __sync_synchronize() or asm("pause") or modify the code like: if (!(ov & BIT_MASKS[bit_index]) && ov == ATOMIC_CAS(&(bits_[byte_index]), ov, ov | BIT_MASKS[bit_index]))

Comment: OK, good to know...also, just to caution, I'm pretty sure that  even `if (!(ov & BIT_MASKS[bit_index]) && ov == ATOMIC_CAS(&(bits_[byte_index]), ov, ov | BIT_MASKS[bit_index]))` might happen to work, I don't think it's reliable; if the former condition is `false`, there's nothing stopping the compiler from doing the exact same optimization as in your original code, and it very well might in a later version of GCC. So you should put an explicit memory barrier, because that's what you need for the semantics to be correct.

Comment: Also, your solutions other might work to prevent the *compiler* from reordering loads, but it does nothing to stop a sufficiently smart *processor* from doing the same.

Comment: Yes, I found that use "volatile" to declare the "bits_", also making the compiler generate correct instructions; But I think that using __sync_synchronize() can make both the compiler and the processor to work correctly

Comment: @user2176204 to be honest (although I think you should put one anyway) you might technically be OK with just `volatile` and without a memory fence here, since a processor (unlike a compiler) will presumably not loop indefinitely based on a cached load, but I'm not 100% sure if it's guaranteed or not. I'm going to post a new question about this, because I'm curious.

Comment: @user2176204 just asked the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467042/can-volatile-but-unfenced-reads-yield-indefinitely-stale-values)

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

The `_Unwind_Resume` function will

> Resume the unwind process, called at the end of cleanup code that didn't return to the normal thread of execution (ie, not a catch).

See [The Secret Life of C++: Day 3: Exceptions](http://www.mit.edu/~sipb-iap/2004/inside-c/day3/exceptions.html)

which according to [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2007-10/msg00263.html)

> It's needed for pthread_cancel.
>   It resumes unwinding after a cleanup.

So it seems there is an exception in a thread for which there is no `catch`... given that the behavior is different with different versions of gcc and different optimization levels I would venture that you are using threads and have a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).